# Why can't I copy and paste all selected key frames on the same timeline?

Tags: keyframes

I'm trying to edit my existing keyframes and I have an issue where I am unable to copy and paste all the selected keyframes; only some of the selected key frames can be pasted. Why?

In the attached example, I have a moving camera and I want it to pause between frames 680 to 700. Usually, all I need do is copy and paste key frames to do this, (e.g., copy key frames at 680 and paste them to 700), but sometimes, like in this example, only some of the selected key frames will paste with the result that the camera keeps moving, influenced by the key frames downstream. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.1, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: I seem to remember sometimes having this problem in the timeline editor, but not in the Graph Editor (Animation workspace).  Until you/we get an expert answer, try using that editor instead (or the Dope Sheet editor as well).

Comment: @james_t Yep, it works from the Graph Editor. That's a workaround. Thanks!